# Gepsio validating Xbrl document

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, xbrl, gepsio

I'm integrating the library `Gepsio` into my current project for `Xbrl` validation.
I'm able to load my document into the `Xbrl` document without any issues. All the content is filled and no exeptions are thrown.

But when i validate the same document against XmlSPy it is not valid.

Am i missing some validation trigger?

I allready tried by downloading your source code and made the constructor of `SummationConceptValidator` public so i could validate my Xbrl fragment to it, still no exceptions.

anybody got some experience with gepsio or should i look for another implementation since this is not supported in the library?

Answer (score 1):

I am Gepsio's author. If you can email me at `gepsio@outlook.com` with details, I will do my best to help you. I'd like to know why XmlSpy thinks the document is invalid. When you email `gepsio@outlook.com`, please send me the XBRL instance document and all related schemas and linkbases. The more information, the better.

Thank you!

Comment: Hey Jeff, i mailed you allready yesterday, did you receive my mail?

Comment: I haven't seen any, but I will take another look now.

Comment: Ah, yes ... the old Junk Mail folder. :) Sorry. Looking now. Thanks for the email!